# event.keyCode return `undefined`

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to run a simple JavaScript function and it does not return the correct value. I want to capture the Enter key code and it doesn't work as expected.

> The code `event.keyCode` returns undefined. In both Chrome and IE 9

My JS:

```
var viewModel = {

    addOnEnter: function (event) {
        alert(event.keyCode);      returns undefined

        var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
        if (keyCode == 13)
        {
            //.. my code
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Binding it like this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="event: { keypress: addOnEnter }" />
```

Both `event.keyCode` and `event.which` returns `undefined`.

Comment: are you binding this to an event some where?

Comment: @WhiteHat, check question again

Comment: I am using knockout library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The event is the second argument to the handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note-2-accessing-the-event-object-or-passing-more-parameters).